# Angular2 long loading app RxJs Observable

Tags: angular

I'm new in Angular 2. I'm doing a simple app with [this tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-2-http-requests-with-observables.).

Everything it's ok (data from REST API are taken correctly), but the application a very long time to load about 5 sec. When I run app I must wait about 5 second for data.

Example: http://embed.plnkr.co/jfUIrVZyajLv8KnDrhL2/
What is wrong?

Comment: Well, this is a common issue, there's a lot of techniques to solve this.
AoT is one of them, will make bundles smaller (will be loaded fastest) if you have a big app.
Check the cdn that is providing the files to your app, maybe there's your delay.
There's other solutions like providing static content to make user feel that the app was loaded and is just fetching data. And as a last comment, the backend of that plunker seems to be offline.

Comment: You can try the profiling function in chrome devtool. Besides the AoT thing, i  recommend you to not have typescript compiler on the client-side.

Comment: My app is small I only use angular to get data from my rest API. Why this example on plnkr.co work very slow?

Comment: On my computer long load too, but I use local back-end.